Showing weekly year-over-year line chart
I had a dumb oversight, in a mockup of a year-over-year line  chart that had an option to view at the weekly level. This listed months with 4 hashmarks between - representing the 4 weeks in a month.
But, then I realized that's an imperfect matchup. There are partial weeks in each month. Short of turning this into a chart with 52 hashlines on the x-axis, which gets pretty busy, how have people solved this challenge?
Here's what I'd done in version 1:


It is fairly common to list week numbers so you could highlight every 4/6/10 weeks, or use 52 hashlines to represent the weeks in addition of 12 bold hashlines to represent the month borders, having these not line up is not really an issue as we all know the weeks and months do not line up in reality, but it still gives the user a sense of time reference.
